# How to apply color scheme to Winmerge under Wine?

Tags: wine, winmerge

I'm running Winmerge (called by Treecomp!) under Wine in Red Hat 7.9
Unfortunately the configuration dialog doesn't show the color schemes that ship with Winmerge, even if they're explicitly imported.

So, did anyone make it work ?

[image]

Comment: The `ColorSchemes` subfolder of the Winmerge installation folder should contain the 4 `.ini` files defining the schemes.